# php function to search array and return count

Tags: php

I'm still learning php and I have tried implementing similar functions that I have seen on this site but can't get any of them to work.  What I want to do is basic and I thought I should have it but can't get it.

Basically I want to return a count of the number of times a string appears in an array.

Here is what I have been trying.  It keeps giving me 0, but should be returning 4 as there are 4 entries that have a logoutTime with May in them.  Thanks in advance for and guidance.  When I try to echo or print $maycount I'am just getting 0.

```
<?php
function MayVPNCount($searchVPNArrayResults, $may){
    $may = 'may';
    $maycount = 0;

    foreach($vpnSessionArray as $oneVPNSession){
        if (strpos($oneVPNSession->logoutTime, $may) !== false)
            $maycount += 1;
        }
    return($maycount);
}
?>
```

Comment: Where does `$vpnSessionArray` come from? Shouldn't you be looping through `$searchVPNArrayResults` instead?

Comment: You're also overriding `$may` with `"may"` before the loop even starts...?

Comment: The function itself is working as expected. Please show either how you fill `$searchVPNArrayResult` or a var_dump of that (and/or `$vpnSessionArray`- what ever the real var name is...).

Comment: First off, the previous commenters have raised good questions (which you really need to address). More than that, how are you calling this function? What's the content of the `$searchVPNArrayResults`? What does `$may` contain? There's too many unknowns here. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Besides the other requests for clarification, you said "there are 4 entries that have a logoutTime with May in them", but you're looking for `may`, not `May`.

Comment: Thanks for the questions, here is the var_dump of $searchVPNArrayResults.

Comment: Couldn't fit all of the output, so here is just one record

array (size=7)

0 => 

object(OneVPNSession)[34]
     
public 'loginTime' => string 'Apr.19 14:02:22' (length=15)

     public 'logoutTime' => string 'Apr.19 14:16:20' (length=15)

     public 'logoutReason' => string 'client logout' (length=13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
function MayVPNCount($searchVPNArrayResults, $may){
    //in this case $searchVPNArrayResults is where Im going to look
    //$may is what Im looking for.

    $text = $searchVPNArrayResults;

    $stringIMlooking = $may;

    $position = 0;
    $maycount = 0;

    //stripos() intead of strpos() for case insensive
    while (($position  = strpos($text, $stringIMlooking, $position ))!== false) {    

    $position  = $position  + strlen($stringIMlooking);


    $maycount++;

    }
    return $maycount;
    }


echo MayVPNCount("the whole text one two tree for one five", "one");
```

you need to change the variables. If you have an array, you could use implode() function to get one string.

As @rickdenhaan said, substr_count() is better:

```
function MayVPNCount($searchVPNArrayResults, $may){

    $text = $searchVPNArrayResults;

    $stringIMlooking = $may;

    //case sensitive
    return substr_count($text, $may) ;

     //case insensituve:
    //return substr_count(strtoupper($text),strtoupper($may));

}
```

Comment: There's too many unknowns in this question for it to be answered. Any answer are basically stabs in the dark. The OP needs to amend the question first.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the concept behind OP's function to try to find the number of objects in an array that have a particular substring in one of its properties. But if you're going to concatenate all entries from the array into a single string, you're probably better off using the native `substr_count()` function instead of writing your own loop to achieve basically the same result.

Comment: Hi @Emeeus,  thanks for the help.  I tried your code and it giving me 2 as the output.  It should be giving me 4 and don't get how/why I keep getting 2.

Comment: @docwobster keep in mid that substr_count and strpos are case sensitive

Comment: @Emeeus thanks again, I got this working now, using substr_count did the trick!